# const references, constructors as parameter, and compilability

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, constructor, g++

A colleague asked me to look over some code he was writing and came across a problem with a particular line, which the compiler (g++) would complain about a function call not having a matching function based on its parameters.

After solving the problem in two ways (one by moving the parameter to its own variable and passing that instead, next is changing the parameter list to take it as a const reference), I had to ask this question: Why is the solution the way it is?  I wasn't satisfied with writing it off as if some constructor details were being hidden away, as my colleague puts it.

As a result, I've replicated and reduced the problem to the following (compile with g++ -Wall -ansi -pedantic):

```
class SomeClass
{
   public:
      static void SomeFunction(SomeClass& sc) {}
      static void SomeFunction2(const SomeClass& sc) {}
};

class SomeChild : public SomeClass {};

void testOne(void)
{
   // this compiles
   SomeChild sc = SomeChild();
   SomeClass::SomeFunction(sc);

   // this doesn't compile
   //SomeClass::SomeFunction(SomeChild());
}

void testTwo(void)
{
   // this compiles
   SomeChild sc = SomeChild();
   SomeClass::SomeFunction2(sc);

   // this compiles
   SomeClass::SomeFunction2(SomeChild());
}

int main(void)
{
   testOne();
   testTwo();

   return 0;
}
```

I'm probably missing something very fundamental here, but can anyone explain to me why the compiler thinks there is no matching function call for the uncompilable line?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple reason is that temporary values, such as the value of `SomeChild()`, cannot bind to non-constant lvalue references. While there's no deep technical reason for this, it's a design choice: non-constant references are usually used to modify the thing that's being referred to, and if that thing is temporary, then the modification would essentially have no lasting effect, which is almost always logic error.

Comment: You make a good point about the temporary scoping issues (since this is all being done on local stack space).  I guess the intention was that the original function in question was only going to be used once, but didn't consider the rule of thumb you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace 'SomeFunction2' by 'SomeFunction':

```
#include <iostream>

class SomeClass
{
   public:
      static void SomeFunction(SomeClass& sc) { std::cout << "not const" << std::endl; }
      static void SomeFunction(const SomeClass& sc) { std::cout << "const" << std::endl; }
};

class SomeChild : public SomeClass {};

int main(void)
{
   SomeChild sc = SomeChild();
   SomeClass::SomeFunction(sc);
   SomeClass::SomeFunction(SomeChild());

   return 0;
}
```

And all is good.

Without the change you bind a temporary to a reference, that is impossible. The only alternatives are 'T', 'const T&' or a universal reference 'T&&' ( http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)

Comment: Keeping in mind that the above example is a reduced variation of the original problem, it should be known that there's only one use case of this particular function call (which took a class derived from boost::function).  In that scenario it probably would be pointless to overload the function.

Comment: This issue is related to non-const references. Changing function name will solve the issue in this trivial case because the compiler will find the proper overload. But, what in a non-trivial case when the two functions are supposed to do different things? Your answer does not explain the reason.

Comment: Right.  'T' would be undesirable since it would effectively waste memory.  'T&&' unfortunately does not exist in C++98 as per the original problem.